# perl hash confusion

Tags: perl, hash, reference, scope

Do you see anything wrong in the below expression.

```
    my $container;
    while (my $val = $details->next()){
          $container->{'total_vals'} += 1;
          my $section_name= 'some string from some db query';
          $container->{"$section_name"}->{'total_vals'} += 1;
    }
    print Dumper $section;
```

above code works when strict is not in use `no strict`. but the second key does not contain a valid value. while if strict sub is in use, i get the below warning. just let me know what I am missing.

`Can't use string ("140360537348481") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at source.pm line 61."`

Comment: `"$section_name"` is not the same thing as `$section . "_name"`, for one thing

Comment: oh yeh that was a typo good catch i corrected it.

Comment: Why are you not Dumping $container? I see no use of $section except for the print statement. That in itself would break with 'use strict'.

Comment: @runrig - yeh i should be dumping the other variable. Its of no use but my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that you probably set `$container->{"$section_name"} = "140360537348481";` at some point.  When you should have done `$container->{"$section_name"} =  {};`.

Comment: kind of yeh ... but I am not sure how can that happen ...  let me check my whole code block again ... yeh perfect .... you are right ... let me make changes there and see what happens

Comment: I was scratching my head since last 1 hr thanks for pointing me to correct track. ... thank you very much ....

Comment: @awake416: it really really helps if you cut and paste the actual code having the problem; when you don't, sometimes answerers can guess correctly anyway, but it makes it less likely.

Comment: @ysth from next time I shall take care.